# Error using mySQL build in operators

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the MySQL build-in operators to get a running total, the query works well when I run it in phpMyAdmin, but running it in php does not work, I just get the "Couldn't execute query" message.

My database connection works fine, thus can I do this in php or is there another way to get this to work?

Here is the script:

```
include("../../include/xxx.inc");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
$query = "SET @runtot:=0;
            SELECT `q1`.`c`, (@runtot := @runtot + `q1`.`c`) AS rt
            FROM (
                SELECT SUM( `sr`.`sr_qty` * `st`.`st_ton` ) AS c, `sr`.`sr_no` 
                FROM `sr` 
                JOIN `st` ON `sr`.`st_code` = `st`.`st_code` 
                WHERE `sr`.`sr_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-15' AND '2015-02-15'
                GROUP BY `sr`.`sr_no` 
                ORDER BY `sr`.`sr_no`) AS q1";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
    or die ("Couldn't execute query.");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($row);
    echo "$rt Ton";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the variable inside the query, so you only have one statement:

```
        SELECT `q1`.`c`, (@runtot := @runtot + `q1`.`c`) AS rt
        FROM (
            SELECT SUM( `sr`.`sr_qty` * `st`.`st_ton` ) AS c, `sr`.`sr_no` 
            FROM (SELECT @runtst := 0) vars cross join
                 `sr` 
            JOIN `st` ON `sr`.`st_code` = `st`.`st_code` 
            WHERE `sr`.`sr_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-15' AND '2015-02-15'
            GROUP BY `sr`.`sr_no` 
            ORDER BY `sr`.`sr_no`) AS q1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but i think it's all your `'s

i would do `SELECT 'q2.c', (@` an so on.

But again, i might be wrong, but it's something to try.

Comment: Yes, you might be wrong. Single quotes create strings, backticks are how you escape names in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run multiple queries with `mysqli_query`. You need to call it separately for each query:

```
$query1 = "SET @runtot:=0"
$query2 = "SELECT `q1`.`c`, (@runtot := @runtot + `q1`.`c`) AS rt
            FROM (
                SELECT SUM( `sr`.`sr_qty` * `st`.`st_ton` ) AS c, `sr`.`sr_no` 
                FROM `sr` 
                JOIN `st` ON `sr`.`st_code` = `st`.`st_code` 
                WHERE `sr`.`sr_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-15' AND '2015-02-15'
                GROUP BY `sr`.`sr_no` 
                ORDER BY `sr`.`sr_no`) AS q1";
mysqli_query($query1);
$result = mysqli_query($query2);
```

You can also put variable initializations into a subquery:

```
$query = "SELECT `q1`.`c`, (@runtot := @runtot + `q1`.`c`) AS rt
            FROM (
                SELECT SUM( `sr`.`sr_qty` * `st`.`st_ton` ) AS c, `sr`.`sr_no` 
                FROM `sr` 
                JOIN `st` ON `sr`.`st_code` = `st`.`st_code` 
                WHERE `sr`.`sr_date` BETWEEN '2015-01-15' AND '2015-02-15'
                GROUP BY `sr`.`sr_no` 
                ORDER BY `sr`.`sr_no`) AS q1
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @runtot := 0) AS init";
```

`mysqli` also has `mysqli_multi_query`, which allows running multiple queries, but I've seen too many people run into problems to recommend it. It's rarely needed, IMHO.